# Dynamic Lambda Select Index

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

I need some help with a LINQ extension that I'm tying to write. I'm trying to create an extension that calculates the row index of a given Id within an IQueryable - Except that type can be any table. I think I've got most of the way there but I just can't seem to complete it. I'm getting the following error message on the line

```
Select(lambda)
```

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
>   Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   c:\users\shawn_000\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\dexconstruktaweb\dexconstruktaweb\generalhelper.cs  157 17  DexConstruktaWeb

```
private class GetRowCountClass
{
    public GetRowCountClass(int id, int index)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Index = index;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

public static int GetRowCount<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int id)
{
    Type sourceType = typeof(T);            
    ParameterExpression[] parameter = new ParameterExpression[2];
    parameter[0]  = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "x");
    parameter[1] = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "index");
    Type getRowCountType = typeof(GetRowCountClass);
    ConstructorInfo constructor = getRowCountType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int)} );

    PropertyInfo pi = sourceType.GetProperty("Id");
    Expression expr = Expression.Property(parameter[0], pi);
    NewExpression member = LambdaExpression.New(constructor,new Expression[] { expr, parameter[1]});

    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(member, parameter);

    var item = query.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(lambda);
}
```

I know that after the select I need the following line to get the index to return, but for now I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).index;
```

**Update**

I've done some further digging and found that some LINQ statements do not work for LINQ to Entities, which is what I'm using:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738551.aspx)

In particular "Most overloads of the projection and filtering methods are supported in LINQ to Entities, with the exception of those that accept a positional argument."

To get around this I was using a call to AsEnumerable() to turn this into a generic Enumerable, then the call to Select and SingleOrDefault as described above. However, I have found that there is no difference in the SQL created between a call to AsEnumerable and ToList, so I have decided to simply call:

```
.ToList().FindIndex(e => e.Id == id)
```

directly on my  IQueryable without creating an Extension as it is a small enough piece of code.

Thanks for all your help. If someone still sees a better way to do this please let me know.

cheers,

**Update 2**

As a bit of a learning exercise I took Servy's suggestion and this answer [Creating Dynamic Predicates- passing in property to a function as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431617/creating-dynamic-predicates-passing-in-property-to-a-function-as-parameter) and came up with the following:

```
public static int GetRowIndex<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, int>> property, int id)
{
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Predicate<T>>(
            Expression.Equal(property.Body, Expression.Constant(id)), property.Parameters);

    return query.ToList().FindIndex(lambda.Compile());
}
```

This can be called like:

```
var result2 = query.GetRowIndex(x => x.Id, id);
```

Where query is of Type IQueryable.

There is very little point to it though and it is only really useful as a learning exercise.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just accept the predicate as a parameter?  If you accept an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` it not only makes this method's implementation pretty trivial, but makes everything statically typed; you don't need to worry about calling it on something that doesn't have an `Id` property, or you could use it to find the index of an item based on something other than its Id.

Comment: @Servy This sounds like a better way to proceed then what I have done so far. Would you mind fleshing it out a little in an answer?

Comment: if you add `.ToList`, or `.AsEnumerable`, then all data from that query will be loaded to server side, and your FindIndex will work on loaded data. It won't be translated into SQL

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov True. But I am not aware of any way to get the Index of an item without returning all the data, while still using LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda always returns `GetRowCountClass` and takes `T` so you can use generic version of `Expression.Lambda` method:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, GetRowCountClass>>(member, parameter);

var item = query.Select(lambda);

return item.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).Index;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this doesn't work. As I'm using LINQ to Entities I need to include .AsEnumerable() before the Select. However, this gives the error 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,TResult>>)' has some invalid argument –

Comment: Just to clarify, if I don't include AsEnumerable then I get the following error when executing .SingleOrDefault: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Entities.GeneralHelpers.LinqExtensions+GetRowCountClass] Select[Book,GetRowCountClass](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Entities.BLL.Models.Book], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[Entities.BLL.Models.Book,System.Int32,Entities.GeneralHelpers.LinqExtensions+GetRowCountClass]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.